# How to fix 'Hash Sum Mismatch' in Docker Ubuntu 18.04 image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt-get

I'm trying to run docker container with ubuntu and nodejs to run some node application.

Firstly, I've searched for similar error of mine, and all didn't work for me.
For example, command below also have failed.

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as osbuild

RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    apt-get clean && \
    apt-get -y update && \
```

This is not my first time to use this Dockerfile (I almostly reused it), but it fails and I'm so confused.

I'm guessing problem might be update on bionic-things in Ubuntu 18.04 (Just yesterday night... suspicious), or maybe it is problem of docker for mac, but I don't see any possible solution for this problem.

I'm using macOS 10.14.6 and Docker 19.03.4

My Dockerfile is

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04 as osbuild
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    ...
```

It failed with following error message:

```
Err:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/universe amd64 Packages
  Hash Sum mismatch
  ...
  Last modification reported: Sat, 09 Nov 2019 01:06:44 +0000
  Release file created at: Sat, 09 Nov 2019 01:05:59 +0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was update on Ubuntu dist, including my problem dir.
Update was done at 2019-11-10 19:18, and now I can build docker image without error.